# calling third party api using httpurlconnection

Tags: java, spring, rest, httpurlconnection

I am trying to call third party api from my controller to get token (POST request) but getting 400, we are using java.net.HttpURLConnection

I tried adding different type of header used but no luck, I also tried with RESTTemplate but same issue. same is working in swagger UI provided by third party, I searched over internet and tried different solution but no luck.

```
public String getToken(String requestJsonString) {
        String responseJSONString = "";
        URL constructedURL = null;
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = null;
        String url = null;

        url = "any url"; //dummy
        try {
            constructedURL = new URL(url);
            httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) constructedURL.openConnection();
            httpConnection.setDoOutput(Boolean.TRUE);
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod(RaterConstants.POST);
            httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE);
            httpConnection.setRequestProperty("accept", RaterConstants.APPLICATION_JSON);

            OutputStream os = httpConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(requestJsonString.getBytes());
            os.flush();

            InputStream inputStream;
            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
                inputStream = httpConnection.getErrorStream();
            } else {
                inputStream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((inputStream)));
            String output;
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                responseJSONString = output;
            }
            httpConnection.disconnect();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error occurred in AccessTokenData : getToken : " + e.getCause());
        }
        return responseJSONString;
    }
```

Request Header from swagger UI - got it from dev tool

```
POST /Test HTTP/1.1
Host: host
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 87
accept: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: url
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Referer: url
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: PF=Ycbz2Gt6Bwyeguyegyue
```

requestJsonString is correct as I tried in swagger, It might be request headers missing, please help with your expertise. I expect to return 200.

Comment: did you try to write the bytes to `OutputStream` in "UTF-8"?
`os.write(requestJsonString.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"))`

Comment: I tried, same issue, Thank you for your comment

Comment: HTTP 400 code beans "Bad Request". It can be anything, depending on the validation checks done on the server side. Try to achieve a valid request using `curl` or Postman, then check what's the difference when you use your Java program.

Comment: do you an error message in addition to the error code?

Comment: I tried postman getting 400 invalid request, now I will debug from here, but any idea what would be missing, content-Type included

Comment: @KernelMode no error message, it returns a response, 400 and invalid request no error log at my side.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you All for your reply.
Root cause: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded will not work with JSON.
I changed the JSON to normal String with "&" as a separator like below:

```
requestJsonString = "grant_type=abc&client_id=id_123&secret=demoSecret"
```

Now it's working